# Date being saved as null in CakePHP 2.x using FormHelper

Tags: date, cakephp, drop-down-menu, cakephp-2.x

I need to pass data from my form. I have a drop-down with the years to choose from in the view:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Zona.agno',  array(
    'label'         => 'Año',
    'type'          => 'year',     
    'minYear'       => date('Y') ,
    'maxYear'       => date('Y') + 4,
    'orderYear'     => 'asc',
    'dateFormat'    => 'Y',        
    'empty' => '--Seleccione Año--'
));
```

The above displays them, but when I hit submit, debug tells me that the data is empty.

In the database, the data type is `date`.

The controller is:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $this->request->data('Zona.activo', 1);
    if ($this->Zona->save($this->request->data)) {
        $this->mensaje(__('La Zona ha sido creada.'));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    } else {
        $this->mensaje(__('La Zona no ha sido creada, por favor verifica los datos.'), 'error');
    }
}
```

The erros is:

```
$this->validationErrors(array)

Zona(array)
agno(array)
0 Debe ingresar año que aplica
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to save an incomplete date into a `date` field in the database, and because it's invalid, the ORM is setting the field to NULL.

You have two options here:

- **Change the field type in the database to `smallint`**, which is probably what it should have been from the start, considering `agno` (año) translates to `year`.
- **Add two other fields**, so the three produce a valid date:

  ```
  <? echo $this->Form->input('Contact.birthdate', array('type' => 'month')); ?>          
  <? echo $this->Form->input('Contact.birthdate', array('type' => 'day')); ?>
  ```

  But probably this is not what you are after.

Comment: change the field in the database, but you still do not save it

Comment: worked the second option, what if I get the moth data in words, but are well saved, thank you very much